# Sampling with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sample

```
vsample_data = credit_card.sample(n=520, replace='False')

print(vsample_data)
```

Here, I was trying to sample 520 data points from a data set but not able to get correct sample data such that there is an equal probability of having two classes from credit card fraud data-set i.e Class-0( Non- Fraud) and Class-1(Fraud).

Comment: Here, credit_card is the credit card fraud detection data set

Comment: why dont you split it to two datasets one for fraud, one for non-fraud and sample 260 each?

Comment: I'm thinking of a way without splitting

Comment: Could you tell how to sample data such that I can get 520 data points which contain both class-0 and class-1

Comment: Randomly select 260 points for class-0, 260 points for class-1.

Comment: How to specify for Class-0 randomly or class-1 because sample method does not have that

Comment: `vsample_data = pd.concat([credit_card[credit_card["Fraud"] == True].sample(n = 260, replace = 'False'), credit_card[credit_card["Fraud"] == False].sample(n = 260, replace = 'False')], axis=1)`? And then shuffle the rows if you see fit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas random sample with ration 1:1 of specific column entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346421/pandas-random-sample-with-ration-11-of-specific-column-entry)

Comment: Ok I'll see this , Thanks anyways

Comment: If I want to maintain the distribution of the sampled data with the original data how will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'actions': [1, 2, 1, 6, 4], 'fraud': [True, False, True, True, False]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print (pd.concat([frauds.sample(n = 1, replace = 'False'), normal.sample(n = 1, replace = 'False')]))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create a fraud Dataframe

I will use a 10% probability of fraud cases:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'val':[random.randint(0,1000) for _ in range(1000)], 
                 'fraud':list(np.random.binomial(1, 0.1, 1000))})
data.head(10)
```

[out]

```
fraud   val
0   0   359
1   0   731
2   0   146
3   0   975
4   0   295
5   0   467
6   0   366
7   1   69
8   0   18
9   0   297
```

Fraud cases should be oversampled 9 times compared to non-fraud cases.

```
data['weights'] = data.fraud * 9
data['weights'] += 1
```

### Weighted samples

```
spl = data.sample(100,weights=data.weights)
sum(spl.fraud)
```

[out]

```
45
```

Fraud cases are about 50% of the total samples.